# Can't import QGIS library using "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe"

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

I have ArcGIS and QGIS on my Windows 7 system (installed with OSGeo4W64).
Why I can't import qgis library using "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe" ?

**How to fix that?**
P.S. Importing QGIS from OSGeo4W Shell work well (but it's not what I want).

Comment: Have you tried the solution in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222517/how-to-import-qgis-core-in-spyder?rq=1

Comment: Unforunately not, because I don't use PyCharm or Spyder IDE. I use standard Python IDE.

Comment: @underdark OK, I just installed PyCharm and used your solution - it works well. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still can't find solution for standard python IDE, but here is solution for PyCharm IDE: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/222672/35561